# setting up a cron job on cpanel that dn't have the cron job option

Tags: cron, cpanel

please can anyone give me a clue on how to Set up a cronjob to execute my API callback URL once every 15 mins, since my control panel does not have that ability, please i need specifications with examples because am still at the armature level, example: i want to setup a cronjop to execute this API call back url http://shop.site.com/modules/cashenvoy/validation.php every 15 mins and my control panel dn't have the option for direct cronjob setting, please how do i go about to setup a cronjob to execute this URL, thanks ur suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use crontab:

```
# to list current cron jobs
sudo crontab -u username -l

# edit the cron list
sudo crontab -u username -e
```

This proves a terminal where you can edit the cron jobs.

Insert the following:

```
*/15 * * * * curl -s http://shop.site.com/modules/cashenvoy/validation.php
```

This will every 15 minutes silently call the wanted website.

Answer (score 0):

A third party cron job provider may help: http://www.easycron.com.

Disclaimer: I work for easycron.com.

Answer (score 0):

This demo assumes you've already logged in to cPanel

Now let's learn how to setup a cron job

1) Click the **Cron Jobs** icon

[image]

2) Enter the email address where you want the cron job results sent after each time it runs
[image]

3) Now you have to define exactly when and how often you want the cron job to run. This is made easier by using one of the pre-defined or **common settings**

[image]

Notice that by choosing a common setting, all fields are filled in automatically. This also helps you understand what each field means
[image]

If you have a shared hosting account, crons should not be made more regular than once every 10 minutes.

4) Let's choose **Once a week**

[image]

5) Next, enter the command of the script you want to run, including the path (from root). If you are on shared hosting - add nice -n 15 to the end. This ensures that the server gives the cron a lower priority than critical system processes, helping maintain stability and server uptime.
Remember to add "nice -n 15" to the end of your command!

[image]

6) When ready, click **Add New Cron Job**
[image]

That's it! The cron job has been set as you can see here. You can create additional cron jobs, and edit or delete existing ones

[image]

This is the end of the tutorial. You now know how to setup cron jobs in cPanel